# ¿Cómo colocar un botón en un popovers?

Tags: javascript, php, html, bootstrap, bootstrap-5

estoy tratando de poner un botón dentro de un `popovers` pero no me lo muestra el botón. Busque información y solo encontré que tengo que insertar el `"data-html="true"`, pero no me funciona. ¿Alguien que me apoye en este asunto?. Comparto el siguiente código:

```
<span class="d-inline-block" tabindex="0"
      data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-title="<?php echo "$nombre"; ?>" data-bs-trigger="hover focus" data-bs-html="true"
      data-bs-content="<button type='button' class='btn btn-success'>Success</button>">
  <img src="../assets/img/1.png" alt="">
</span>
```

JavaScript:

```
var popoverTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]'))
var popoverList = popoverTriggerList.map(function (popoverTriggerEl) {
  return new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTriggerEl)
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías hacer uso de la combinación de las opciones `html` y `selector` así:

- Indicamos que `html` es `true`
- Indicamos en `content` el [`selector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) al elemento que queremos que aparezca dentro del contenido del `Popover`

Luego nos queda modificar el `javascript` que inicializa los `Popover` para que realice la consideraciones mencionadas.

#### Ejemplo:

```js
var popoverTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]'))
var popoverList = popoverTriggerList.map(function(popoverTriggerEl) {
  // Creamos la configuración
  let config = {}
  // Si es HTML = true, usamos el valor de `data-bs-content` como un selector
  if (popoverTriggerEl.dataset.bsHtml === 'true') 
    config.content = document.querySelector(popoverTriggerEl.dataset.bsContent);
  // Pasamos la configuración al constructor
  return new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTriggerEl, config)
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<span class="d-inline-block" tabindex="0" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-title="Titulo del popover" data-bs-trigger="hover focus" data-bs-html="true" data-bs-content="#contenido">
  Clic para abrir popover
</span>
<div hidden>
  <div id="contenido">
    <b>Clic en el botón</b>
    <button type='button' class='btn btn-success'>Success</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Entiendo, no pensé que también se podría indicar el HTML en JavaScript voy a ver si tu enseñanza me funciona

Comment: Ya probé y no me funciona, no muestra el popover :(

Comment: Me arroja este error: Uncaught TypeError: bootstrap.Popover.prototype._mergeConfigObj is not a function

Comment: Hola @ALAN, evidentemente no estamos usando la misma versión del JS. Actualice mi respuesta para hacerla compatible con cualquier versión.

Comment: o ya veo, una disculpa apenas voy a prendiendo en esto, voy a probar de nuevo

Comment: ya corregí y ya me muestra el popover pero no el button

Comment: @ALAN, ¿podrías crear un [`CodePen`](https://codepen.io/pen/) con tu código actual y compartirme el link?

Comment: Te lo puedo compartir por collabedit ya que por CodePen no se como hacerlo ? @Marcos  La ruta es:  https://collabedit.com/k3225

Comment: @ALAN, cree [esta demo](https://jsfiddle.net/o09j2esq/) y veo que si funciona. Viendo tu código diría que probablemente tenes algún conflicto con todos los archivos `javascript` que cargas.

Comment: Entonces checare cual es el script de JavaScript que me esta causando problemas, gracias por la observación y el apoyo @Marcos